# What kind of quarrel is described in Exodus 21:18

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, shemot-exodus, mishpatim

> וְכִי־יְרִיבֻן אֲנָשִׁים וְהִכָּה־אִישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵהוּ בְּאֶבֶן אוֹ
> בְאֶגְרֹף וְלֹא יָמוּת וְנָפַל לְמִשְׁכָּב׃
>
> When men quarrel and one strikes the other with stone or fist, and he
> does not die but has to take to his bed—
> ([Exodus 21:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.21.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Is this referring to a quarrel that started verbally and then became physical by an agreement between both involved? Or does it refer to a verbal quarrel where one person chooses to make the fight physical?

If it is the latter, is there any difference if the person who did not initiate the physical fight chooses to or to not fight back? Whether he acts offensively, by trying to hurt the other, or only acts defensively, by only protecting himself?

Answer (score 1):

The Netziv in [Ha'amek Davar](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.21.18?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Haamek_Davar_on_Exodus.21.18.1&lang2=bi) seems to imply that this altercation started as a verbal quarrel.

He writes there:

> וכי יריבן אנשים. **ריב הוא בדברים** ועושק כמו ריבך ריב את רעך וסוד אחר אל תגל<sup>1</sup> וכן הרבה. והיה להמקרא להתחיל הענין וכי יכה איש את רעהו וגו׳ אלא מלמדנו שאע״ג שהניזק גרם לכך בשביל **שהכה להמזיק בשוט לשון**<sup>2</sup> מ״מ ישנו בדין הפרשה. ובסמוך יבואר עוד נ״מ בזה הריב שקדם להכאה
>
> And when men quarrel. **It is a quarrel with words** and one party withholding something from the other. Like "Defend your right against your fellow, but do not give away the secrets of another" ([Mishlei 25:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.25.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)).<sup>1</sup> And the verse had to begin by stating "When a man hits his friend" only to teach us that even though the damage was caused by **the hit of a scornful tongue**,<sup>2</sup> nevertheless it was to teach the law of this matter. And moreover it explains a practical halachic difference in the fact that the quarrel came before the hitting.

---

<sup>1</sup> Refer to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.25.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Proverbs.25.9.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) on the verse in Mishlei there which speaks specifically about the type of quarrel that is debated verbally. He writes there:

> ריבך ריב את רעך. ואם על כרחך אתה צריך לריב ולהוכיח עם רעך מ"מ סוד אחר אל תגל לא תזכיר לו דופי אבותיו שמתו שאין הכל יודעין אותו ואתה מגלהו:
>
> Have your quarrel with your friend But if, perforce, you must quarrel and debate with your friend, in any event, do not divulge another’s secret Do not mention to him the disgrace of his ancestors, which not everyone knows, and you are revealing it. (Sefaria translation & notation)

<sup>2</sup> This term "בשוט לשון" is used in [Iyov 5:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.5.21?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> בְּשׁ֣וֹט לָ֭שׁוֹן תֵּחָבֵ֑א וְֽלֹא־תִירָ֥א מִ֝שֹּׁ֗ד כִּ֣י יָבֽוֹא׃
>
> You will be sheltered from the scourging tongue; You will have no fear when violence comes. (Sefaria translation)

[Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Job.5.21.1?lang=bi) and [Metzudas Dovid](https://www.sefaria.org/Metzudat_David_on_Job.5.21.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explain the expression as being tied to the action of saying lashon harah.